# Do we consider having a Youtube video as an answer acceptable?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, youtube-embed

Taken from [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/90363/what-technically-defines-what-a-nether-fortress-is-in-terms-of-mob-spawning/90376#90376).

Is @BlaXpirit's answer too vague?  I understand that he didn't explain what was going on in the videos, but merely linking them and saying "Watch them, you'll get your answer that way."

Are we supposed to support our videos with text? Or are we supposed to simply place videos into answers without explanations?

Comment: Most of the time, I would say yes, support your video link with text, but there's so much information in that first video, and it's so well presented, that it'd be an injustice to try and summarize it.

Comment: So, if the video explains it well enough, is it a good enough excuse to not add text to an answer?

Comment: Does BlaXpirit's answer stand on its own without the videos? No, it doesn't. Could he have done more to add some explanation? Yes. Can someone write a suitable answer without using a video? Probably, but can it also be done without pictures? Probably not.  You didn't succeed, as indicated by the vote counts (although you didn't really answer the question to begin with). The use of video is almost a necessity here, so take that into consideration.

Comment: It's not about my question.  I know my question didn't succeed (question title was unclear), but it's not like this a is a personal feud or something.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that. It's more that one person (anyone really) has tried and failed at providing a text only answer, whereas someone who linked a video succeeded.  As the only other answer on the question, it makes for an easy point of comparison.

Comment: What do you really mean by "frown upon"? Do you mean, "will moderators delete it as not an answer", or just "will people tend to downvote it?"

Comment: FYI you linked the wrong answer. Should be http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/90376/1298

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Just like link-only answers, the answer should be able to stand on its own feet even if the video becomes deleted/private/unavailable in your region/gets taken down or if youtube embedding doesn't work.

Comment: In general I agree, but sometimes it's not easy to summarize a complete video, and I don't think that's a reason not to post it... though in these cases, at least provide a brief description of it.

Comment: @Oak That's a reasonable objection.

Comment: "Brief description, at minimum" is a good guideline, I think.

Comment: The consensus is that writing filler text is somehow useful, so you should do that even when linking to a comprehensive answer.

Comment: @Decency No, the consensus is that all answers should be *answers*, not links to things that are answers.  We're a Q&A site, not a search engine, so if you can't find the solution to your problem somewhere in an answer post then it's not actually an answer.  Links for references and further detail are awesome but they are not answers.

Comment: @MatthewRead I understand the policy, I just don't think it makes much sense when dealing with anything beyond a simple code snippet from documentation or a line of text from a wiki. When you have questions that involve huge depth and nuance, your options are essentially to not allow the questions (and many of the best questions on the site are of this type), or to allow answers that are almost entirely useless without the content in their links. The in-between pretense that two sentences can accurate summarize an essay or video is ludicrous.

Comment: @Decency Some answers require more than two sentences, sure.  I agree that an inadequate summary is not sufficient, but I don't think that's what is being promoted here.  I've written 1000+ word answers (on Android at least) that are basically just summaries of other content.

Comment: @MatthewRead Sure, and that's the exact behavior that generally is a complete waste of time and detrimental to the original creator of that information- linked to or not. Especially in the gaming world where content producers typically rely on viewers to produce more content, pulling those viewers from them is nontrivial.

Comment: @Decency "Go look here" is one step away from "Let me Google that for you".  I don't like it and I prefer having a complete resource here, personally.

Comment: @MatthewRead A search engine that returns exactly one result which is guaranteed to answer your question is a much improved LMGTFY. ;)

Comment: @Decency I agree that there's a big difference between crafting answers and rephrasing "content". Honestly, however, the Stack Exchange is at least _supposed_ to be an answer crafting community and just linking to other sites _isn't_ "content creation." In other words, you shouldn't take the easy way out and get reputation for what others have written. (Also, yes, questions that require books for answers _should_ be closed.)

Comment: @Decency If the video is complex enough to resist summarising, then the answer should at least give some *hint* as to what the answer was about should the video disappear. "Here is a video that answers your question: [dead link]" is a bad answer. "Here is a video that demonstrates how to use pistons to build a complex long-tick clock, instead of using repeaters like you were thinking of doing: [dead link]" is a much, much better answer. It gives future readers some leads to work with even if the link rots.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I feel like I'd appreciate the 'dead link' argument that comes up so much if it had more validity- I have yet to encounter a dead link on the site. Even if it does come up, many users have the ability to edit answers with an updated link in the event of something like that happening, which pretty much negates the entire approach. It's nice in theory, but I'd prefer a practical policy that at least somewhat resembles reality. Another solution that I mentioned earlier in another topic is just to quote something very identifiable from the link to use as a lead.

Comment: @Decency I have. The "this video is no longer available" thing happens more when you live outside the US. Even more frequent is the "this video is not available on your device". It's a rather *relevant* argument for me. :) And editing the answer to update a dead link is dependent on a number of factors: Is the original answerer still around to fix it? If not, does anyone remember what the answer was? If yes, does any proper replacement exist? That's too many ways the answer can break. Having at least an insufficient summary means that we don't rely on memory or the original answerer to fix it.

Comment: @Decency Regardless of the dead link argument though, do you disagree that the second answer is objectively better than the first?

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It's better if (and only if) the link is dead. Otherwise it's just filler text that doesn't tell you how to actually solve the problem.

Comment: @Decency That's assuming that the answer is *correct*, which is not always the case: It is also better for evaluating whether I want to use my precious time watching a (e.g.) 20 minute video that might actually not adequately answer the question. A summary is like a title: it gives some hints about whether what follows is useful or trash. We can't make policy by assuming that users are perfect – we must make policy that is *robust* against incompetence. That is the whole point of the structure of the site. Summaries are a fail-safe in many ways.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie That's the role of upvotes to me- if an answer is highly upvoted the community has deemed it accurate, relevant, and useful. If it's highly downvoted, it's probably wrong. All of us are (supposedly) smarter than one of us.

Comment: @Decency Part of the "links may go dead" policy is also intended to prevent people from - say - posting answers to questions on their own off-site blog and then ad.fly'ing the hell out of us ("This site has the answer!"). We've already have had people shamelessly "enriching" our _blog_ with own outside links for the ad revenue.

Comment: @Decency If upvotes were all we needed, then we wouldn't need any policies, mods, deletion, flags, editing capabilities, or anything else. Votes are not the universal solvent, and the site is not designed to treat them that way. *That* way lies Yahoo Answers. You don't want us to be Yahoo Answers, do you? :)

Comment: Anyway, I've said my piece in attempting to explain why the consensus is against your position. I'm afraid we may just go in circles from here, so I say *adieu* now. Cheers!

Comment: @SevenSidedDie There is a middle ground between authoritarianism and letting voters rule, which is why we have those tools in addition to voting. If you need moderation to decide when an answer is useful or relevant, you might as well not allow voting at all. I expect [Discourse](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2013/02/civilized-discourse-construction-kit.html) to be more in line with my ideals.

Comment: @Decency Aaaand the circle begins. I choose not to complete it. The matter appears to be resolved, continued jawing notwithstanding. If you'd like to know why, there is lots to re-read. Good day!

Comment: @Decency You know that Discourse isn't like "SE but a forum"...but instead, is a platform for people to buy and use on their own sites? See [here](http://www.discourse.org/buy/). It's not going to be a network like SE is. It is a completely different animal. Also, read [this](http://www.discourse.org/faq/).

Comment: @AshleyNunn Yep. There will no doubt be communities around gaming that spring up using the software.

Comment: ...and they'll be forums for discussion, not Q&A sites.  I really don't see how Discourse relates to the question.

Comment: I hate the new trend of using a video to show how to do things. It smacks of laziness, and you just can't skip to the relevant portion without watching the whole damn thing. There are Youtube videos for Windows registry hacks for heavens' sake!

Comment: @Rex It depends on the subject matter, honestly. It would be rather tedious to explain where to find all the revolver parts in Borderlands in text form, but [even a crappy video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SkOEEfGAaq4) can show off an answer with greater clarity and immediacy. Of course, it helps if the video is made by the answerer ;)

Comment: Yes, but I'm talking about cases where a simple paragraph would have sufficed. A game walkthrough might be easier to explain with a video, but I don't see the point with registry tweaks, commandline parameters and things that are easier to copy paste, when you obviously can't do that from a video!

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft From what I can tell it will be a bit in between, where Q&A can take the form of more than the silly restrictions we have here.

Comment: What if you made a video specificaly for that answer?

Comment: @Paralytic That would be the most awesome thing. It still wouldn't be enough because videos get their content identified, taken down in some regions (or all of them)...

Comment: @badp typically videos are only not shown in some regions because of music.

Answer (score -2):

1. Yes,  we are supposed to support our videos with text, in as much that the text alone answers the question.
2. No,  we are not supposed to simply place videos into answers without explanations.

From [How do I write a good answer?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer):

> Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context
>   around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is
>   and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an
>   important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes
>   permanently offline.

Unfortunately, being able to embed videos, makes people consider them "part" of SE.

Nevertheless, just like with [link-only answers](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4336/what-should-we-do-with-answers-containing-only-a-link-to-relevant-information), video-only "answers" should be converted to comments below the question (so that they are not answers any more):

> If the author does not improve the answer and if no other user goes
>   ahead and edits the post, it should be converted to a comment. It
>   still might contain valuable information, but a link alone is not an
>   answer by SE standards.

Comment: Do you mean you should explain the answer in text?

Comment: so.. you still havnt corrected the issue I see. Comments are these little footnotes at the bottom of the question. A video, with the author explaining it in the comment section, is still not an acceptable answer. Likewise, if extra information is provided in the comments, it should be edited into the actual question/answer.

Comment: A video only answer could be deleted, but in effect, it should never really be. If it really comes down to it, add the text version yourself. If it involves a lot of effort, by all means. Take that users video, watch it, and post the text version as your own answer. Think of it this way, comments are used for clarification. If a user comes on looking for an answer, we would hope that recieve the information they are after, without having to read through all the comments. Furthermore, comments can be condensed. If there are too many, you have to click an "expand" tab to view them.